# How to show svg icon instead of mouse cursor in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js with material UI. I am new to react js. I want to show svg image instead of mouse cursor when the mouse is moving on canvas. Please help. I want to assign svg url to canvas.defaultCursor. So that cursor will show svg icon. Please help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You do need JS for that. Just apply a CSS style to that element:

```css
.pointer {cursor: pointer;}
.svg {cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='32px' height='32px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath d='M443.6,387.1L312.4,255.4l131.5-130c5.4-5.4,5.4-14.2,0-19.6l-37.4-37.6c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4 L256,197.8L124.9,68.3c-2.6-2.6-6.1-4-9.8-4c-3.7,0-7.2,1.5-9.8,4L68,105.9c-5.4,5.4-5.4,14.2,0,19.6l131.5,130L68.4,387.1 c-2.6,2.6-4.1,6.1-4.1,9.8c0,3.7,1.4,7.2,4.1,9.8l37.4,37.6c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1L256,313.1l130.7,131.1 c2.7,2.7,6.2,4.1,9.8,4.1c3.5,0,7.1-1.3,9.8-4.1l37.4-37.6c2.6-2.6,4.1-6.1,4.1-9.8C447.7,393.2,446.2,389.7,443.6,387.1z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer">POINTER</div>
<div class="svg">SVG</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But I want to assign svg image to defaultCursor property of canvas which is the part of fabricjs. So that the cursor will change to svg image. So you have any idea about this?How can I do this? E.g. If I write canvas.defaultCursor = "move" then it will show move cursor. Now I want to assign svg over there. Please help.

Comment: Nowhere have you mentioned fabric.js in your question and even than CSS approach is applicable.

Comment: I used your approach only in fabric js and it worked as magic. Thank you so much for your help.